# HttpContextAcessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Etag",somevalue) not working in unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to write a unit testing and I am having some controller methods to call, and inside we have some service called `utilityservice` with a method `SetTag()` which is setting value from

```
HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Etag", somevalue)
```

While trying to get the value using

```
HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Etag")
```

I get an error

> Object reference error

Can someone please help? I tried a lot of research and I'm still facing this issues - and have for 4 days.

Comment: Hi @Nagu V, the issue means the object is null which cannot access the property for this object. Pls share more code.

Comment: You need to setup your test project to mock session. Can you share some screen shot or code, how you have setup the test?